# The correct way of using %in% within apply function

Tags: r, function, apply, scanf

New to R so have some basic and stupid questions. Hope that I could learn from all the experienced masters here and became someone who could be helpful to all other data experts as well in the near future.

My target is to check each row of `test` if `id` is listed in `id_lag` in the same row. My sample code is as follows:

```
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,10,3))
names(test) <- c("Year","id","id_lag")
test[,1] <- c(2011,2012,2013,2010,2014,2015,2016,2010,2011,2012)
test[,2] <- c(76,560,342,7908,200,23,23,890,780,150)
test[,3] <- c("76,89","209,2000,400","342,333,234","908,888","","23","8097,5678","12","780,209","150,4504")

involved <- function(id,id_lag)
{
 a <- return(id %in% scan(what = "", sep = ",",text = id_lag) )
 return(a)
}



check <- apply(test, 1, function(x,y) involved(test$id,test$id_lag))
```

I'm expecting a 1 by 10 list as `TRUE` or `FALSE` if it listed in this row or not. However, I'm getting a 10 by 10 matrix with `TRUE` or `FALSE` that scanned the entire list 10 times. Is there any way I can eliminate this apply function only scan through line rather than do the full scan of whole list? Or is there any better approach say data.tables etc that would work?

Thanks,
Anne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)` applies a function across the rows of a matrix if `MARGIN = 1` and across the columns if `MARGIN = 2`.

What you have done with

```
check <- apply(test, 1, function(x,y) involved(test$id,test$id_lag))
```

is "call the function `involved(test$id,test$id_lag)` for each row of the `text` matrix". So you end up with a 10x10 matrix because you have called `involved(test$id,test$id_lag)` once for each of the 10 rows of `test`.

If you want to apply a function across a row while taking the elements of multiple columns as arguments for each function call, `mapply()` is a useful function. Perhaps something like:

```
mapply( function(x,y) involved(x,y), x = test$id, y = test$id_lag )
```

Comment: Would explore more on the apply function family. Thanks!